# Error reading an XML with a tag inside an attribute

Tags: asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc

I'm reading some XML files with this code (I'm using ASP MVC)

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";
httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(result);
```

where requestUrl is some Url I passed to the code. The Url contains the XML, I don't have access to it.

This works fine. The problem is, one of the XML files I'm reading has this < img> tag with another tags inside (the problem is in the alt attribute, there are other tags but I'm omitting them):

> < img alt=": < p>I have some text here< /p>" />

I can't read this because of this < p> inside < img>. When I tried, I have a XML Exception. I think this is an error in the XML, but I want to know if there is some way to read this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
< img alt="Alexandrino Alencar, da Odebrecht" />
```

Comment: I don't have access to the XML. I'm reading it from a site. I'm looking for some way to read this the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<` & `>` the numeric character reference should be used `&#60;` & `&#62;` otherwise the parser will throw an exception as it sees `<` twice.

If you are not generating them then perhaps you could pre-process them and convert them to the numerical character reference according to the special characters in XML [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

Comment: I think pre-process is really the only way. I did this and it worked. When I asked this question I was looking for some way to "force" the code to read the XML, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Sorry how do you mean by force the code? XML parser would not know how to make sense of two `<` in a row so I don't think there is any way of forcing it.